# Django many-to-many relations

Tags: python, django, database, many-to-many, user-accounts

I'm trying to create a web app in which users can participate in some groups (every user can be part of multiple groups), and I want to be able to make both queries like

```
group.users_set()
```

and

```
user.groups_set()
```

I want to see all groups a user is participating to in the admin page of every user and vice versa. My last attempt was this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='Participation')

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    group_password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    customusers = models.ManyToManyField('CustomUser', through='Participation')

class Participation(models.Model):
    customuser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but I get

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'userreg.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E013) The value of 'fieldsets[2][1]["fields"]' cannot include the ManyToManyField 'groups', because that field manually specifies a relationship model.
```

Before, with just

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
```

in the Group class and without the Participation class, I was able to get half of my goal, seeing the list of logged users in the admin page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) should only be in ONE of your models.  BOTH models will still have access to the other even though the ManyToManyField is defined in only one of the models.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Then, why wasn't I seeing groups a user was logged in before? Should I modify admin.py to see them? And if yes, how?

Comment: @davide: because the default name of the relation in reverse is `group_set`, not `groups`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @Willem Van Onsem was very useful, but I solved my problem doing this in models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group')

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUsers)
```

and this in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Group, CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['group_name', 'group_password']}),
        ('Users', {'fields': ['users']}),
    ]

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['username', 'password']}),
        ('Groups', {'fields': ['groups']}),
    ]
    

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2):

You specify a `ManyToManyField` in one of the two models, so for example:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Group',
        related_name='users'
        through='Participation'
    )

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Participation(models.Model):
    customuser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) specifies the name of the relation in reverse, so from `Group` to `CustomUser`, and you thus can rename this to `users` as is here the case. If you do not specify one, the default is `modelname_set` with *`modelname`* the name of the model (here `CustomUser`) in lowercase (so `customuser`).

Since your [**`through=…`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) only has two `ForeignKey`s to the two models, you do not need to create one, and you can simplify this further to:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Group',
        related_name='users'
    )

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```